# PHP: Check if my string only contains numbers and "X" character

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I retrieve the next values of my size products: 30X50 or 20x20

I want add the "cm" measure if this values contains the character x or X and only numbers.

```
@if($myvalue contains only the character x and numbers)
 {{ $myvalue }} cm // like 20x20cm
@endif
```

I need a regular expression. I try with this:

```
@if (preg_match('/^\d*(x|X){1}\d*$/',$item->name)) cm.@endif
```

But not works

Comment: How to get a regular expression is your question? Well, by writing it. For that you have to learn about regular expressions. Did you start doing that?

Comment: Please note that SO is _not_ a free coding service. We are _not_ here to do your work for you. We are here to help with _specific issues_ you encounter _in your own code_. So start out yourself, if you run into serious issues, _then_ is the time to come here, post your code and point out that issue you ran into.

Comment: Tips: https://regex101.com and http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php This does not require a difficult regex.

Comment: @arkascha I edit the main post

Answer (score 0):

Don't use regular expression in such a trivial case. For example you can write your own domain parse function.

```
/**
 * Parse dimension
 *
 * @return array [dimX, dimY] or empty array when invalid input
 */
function parse(string $meta): array {

    $parseTree = explode('x', strtolower($meta));

    if (2 != \count($parseTree)
            || !ctype_digit($parseTree[0])
                || !ctype_digit($parseTree[1])) {
        return [];
    }

    return $parseTree;

}


/**
 * Test {@see parse}
 * @throws \LogicException When test failed
 */
function testParse() {

    $dataProvider = [
        ['20x50', [20, 50]],
        ['20X50', [20, 50]],
        ['20z50', []],
        ['a20x50', []],
        ['20xa50', []],
    ];


    foreach($dataProvider as $serie) {
        if (parse($serie[0]) != $serie[1]) {
            throw new \LogicException('Test failed');
        }
    }

}


testParse();
```

Comment: Less flexible, maintanable when working with domain data.

Comment: As long as you're only using primitive types, regex is the way to go. With custom code you're way less flexible than with a regex. Custom code is also slower, and much more resource dependent. Only when you cannot work with regex's (object data), custom code is the way to go.

Comment: There is a diffrence beetwen parsing and validating domain data and processing input. For example i can have many validating decorator function etc.